# Control Fan Speed Using ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, pwm

Hello i am using ESP8266 to control my 220v AC ceiling fan.

I am able to do that easily with a 5v 10A relay module.

But i want to know is there any module to control the fan speed as well? i have checked many videos on YouTube but couldnt understand how can i do that. I just got one thing that it will require Pulse Width Modulation to control it.

Thank you!

Comment: `I just got one thing that it will require Pulse Width Modulation to control it` huh? what?

Comment: to control Celling fan speed

Comment: no, pwm will not help you. the trick is to turn the relay on and off fast. the mechanical relay cant do it, so you need a SSR (solid state relay)

Comment: @Juraj Thank you for amazing suggestion. But can you share any example code? Or any library which can help with this?

Comment: Blink example ?

Comment: code example..that can be any of the possible one. Just want to test it.

Comment: yes Blink. turn on, turn off, turn on, turn off, turn on, turn off,...

Comment: you can use "pwm", but not what us makers call pwm, which is a high-frequency DC thing, and you need a low frequency AC thing. It's called phase modulation, and uses a triac. it's a lot more complicated than DC PWM. Look into zero crossing SSRs to make your task half as difficult.

Comment: @dandavis do you think this will work? https://robu.in/product/5v-4-channel-ssr-solid-state-relay-module-240v-2a-output-resistive-fuse/